# Графическое оформление списка

Tags: html, css

Подскажите по списку с оформлением. Что изменить в коде, чтобы если было больше одной строчки в абзаце не сжимался background для номера? Возможно нужно ввести какое-нибудь выравнивание текста?

```css
.num2 {
  color: white;
  background: #5389ED;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1px 6px;
  line-height: 32px;
  line-width: 32px;
  width: 32px;
border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans";
font-size: 14pt;
margin-left:1px;
}
.cont1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.p2 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-align: justify;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont1">
  <div class="num2">
    1</div>
  <div class="p2">
    Апрель 1945-го.</div>
</div>
<div class="cont1">
  <div class="num2">
    2</div>
  <div class="p2">
    Американские войска ведут ожесточенные бои с японцами на острове Окинава. Пулеметный шквал и прицельный минометный огонь</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант дать кругам `position:absolute;` :

```css
.num2 {
  color: white;
  background: #5389ED;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1px 6px;
  line-height: 32px;
  line-width: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans";
  font-size: 14pt;
  margin-left: 1px;
  position: absolute;
}
.cont1 {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.p2 {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont1">
  <div class="num2">
    1</div>
  <div class="p2">
    Апрель 1945-го.</div>
</div>
<div class="cont1">
  <div class="num2">
    2</div>
  <div class="p2">
    Американские войска ведут ожесточенные бои с японцами на острове Окинава. Пулеметный шквал и прицельный минометный огонь</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, отступ слева решил попробовать через "padding-left: 5%;"